# Need to chunk strings into 140-character chunks while respecting words

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a very simple problem but need a solution that works. I have a node script that opens a text file, loops over each line and chunks the line if its over 140 characters but needs to respect word boundaries. This is what I have so far but the lines come out unaffected. I've also tried `_.invoke(lines, function() { splitText(this); };` but this also leaves the lines unaffected. Can anyone suggest another way of doing this?

```
var args = process.argv.splice(2),
    fs = require('fs'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    splitText;

splitText = function (textSegment) {
    var len = 140, curr = len, prev = 0, output = [], currReverse;
    while (textSegment[curr]) {
        if (textSegment[curr++] == ' ') {
            output.push(textSegment.substring(prev, curr));
            prev = curr;
            curr += len;
        } else {
            currReverse = curr;

            do {
                if (textSegment.substring(currReverse - 1, currReverse) == ' ') {
                    output.push(textSegment.substring(prev, currReverse));
                    prev = currReverse;
                    curr = currReverse + len;
                    break;
                }
                currReverse--;
            } while (currReverse > prev);
        }
    }
    output.push(textSegment.substring(prev));
    return output;
}

text = fs.readFileSync(args[0], 'utf-8');

lines = text.split("\n");

lines = _.filter(lines, function (line) {
    return line.length >= 100;
});

lines = _.map(lines, function (line) {
    return splitText(line);
});

fs.writeFile(args[0], lines.join("\n"), function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('test');
});
```

Comment: To answer your question title: Count the words, divide by 140.
To answer the question in the first paragraph: check if the 140th character is a space, if so - cut it, if not, go one character back and repeat.

Comment: Kylee, was the answer I posted what you were looking for? If it was, please mark it as 'accepted', so that others can see this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with underscore.js, but I do know a fairly straightforward way to fix this without it:

```
function formatStr(text, len) {
    len = len||140;
    var i=0,
        str, newline, breakpt,
        formatted = '';

    while (i+len<text.length) {
        str = text.substr(i, len);
        newline = str.indexOf('\n');
        if (newline!=-1) {
            formatted += str.substr(0,newline+1);
            console.log(i,newline);
            i += newline + 1;
            continue;
        }
        breakpt = str.lastIndexOf(' ');
        formatted += str.substr(0,breakpt) + '\n';
        i+=breakpt+1;
    }
    // add last line to the end and return; credit to Charly
    // for mentioning this was missing.
    return formatted + text.substr(i);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/cizewoseko)

What this loop does is the following:

- Store the next 140 characters in a var
- test if there are already any newlines in this string

  - if so, just add that part of the string to the formatted string, and `continue` from there
- get the last index of a space in the string variable
- append the part of the string until the next space in the formatted string
- finally, return the formatted string.

Comment: You method has a side effect : the very last segment of the input text is not rendered.  
In your demo, the output finished as `Phasellus tellus` while the input finished as `Phasellus tellus quam, ultricies hendrerit leo et, congue venenatis eros. Donec cursus porta orci, id convallis ipsum elementum egestas.`  I think you should do `formatted += text.substr(i);` after the loop

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I've added it to the code in the answer and to the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old thread but here's a quick solution.

Try this regex, you can see how it works here: http://regexper.com/#%5E(%5Cr%5Cn%7C.)%7B1%2C140%7D%5Cb

```
str.match(/^(\r\n|.){1,140}\b/g).join('')
```